# Pandas: Remove rows except the first new occurrence of a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
x y
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 0
e 0
f 0
g 1
h 1
i 0
j 0
```

I want to remove the rows with 0 except every first new occurence of 0 after 1, so the resultant dataframe should be

```
x y
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 0
g 1
h 1
i 0
```

Is it possible to do it without creating groups or row by row iteration to make it faster since I have a big dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `diff` with `cumsum` create the continue value group , then try `duplicated`

```
out = df[~df.y.diff().ne(0).cumsum().duplicated() | df.y].copy()
Out[352]: 
   x  y
0  a  1
1  b  1
2  c  1
3  d  0
6  g  1
7  h  1
8  i  0
```

Comment: This little gem makes the pandas gods smile.  Nice one mate.

Comment: Thanks. This one seems slightly faster than wwnde's code. For processing around 5 million rows which includes other cleanup operations, this one is around 10 seconds faster. I have to do standalone benchmarking before confirming on this.

Answer (score 2):

Check consecutive similarity using shift()

```
 df[df.y.ne(0)|(df.y.eq(0)&df.y.shift(1).ne(0))]



  x  y
0  a  1
1  b  1
2  c  1
3  d  0
6  g  1
7  h  1
8  i  0
```

Comment: Any reason you modified your earlier answer, df[~(df.y.eq(0) & df.y.shift(-1).eq(0))] ?

Comment: That was not entirely capturing. `~` means reversion of a condition. I preferred to give the direct outcome and not the reversed because it can be harder to read. Apart from just writing a working code, can we also make it readable? This is always an important question.